# Iterating through a range until you find different value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a VBA function that starts from the bottom of a range, and returns the first value that's different from the value at the bottom.

Example:

[image: Sample Excel Table]

In the above table, I'd like to be able to grab the last value in the "Month" column (11), and iterate to the top until the value 10 is reached, and return that value.

I just started looking into VBA 3 days ago and am very unfamiliar with the language so I'm still trying to grok the syntax.

I have no doubt that my thinking is fuzzy with this, so I'd really appreciate feedback on my errors.

Here's what I have right now:

**Code:**

```
Function NextValue(num1 As Range)
For c = num1.End(xlDown) To num1.Item(1)
    If Cells(c, 1) <> num1.End(xlDown) Then
        NextValue = Cells(c, 1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next c
End Function
```

In case it's not clear, here's a description of what I'm trying to do, line-by-line.

1).  Initiate a For-Loop that begins at the end of a range and decrements to the top

2).  Check if that cell does not match the last value in that column

3).  If it does not, then set the value of the function to that value

4).  Terminate If statements, For loops, and end the function.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you need VBA ? FYI you can do this with a normal cell function.

Comment: No, I don't need it to do it this way if there's an easier alternative.  Although I do prefer a VBA function over a convoluted non-VBA one that relies on complicated function chaining and esoteric details few people are aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function NextValue(num1 As Range) as Integer
  Dim y As Integer
    'get the last cell from num1
    Set num1 = num1.End(xlDown)

    y = -1
    Do Until num1.Offset(y, 0).Value <> num1.Value
        y = y - 1
    Loop
    'set function return to the different cell
    NextValue = num1.Offset(y, 0).value
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but it returns the #VALUE! error when I use it on a range.

Comment: So your input is a range of cells, not just the last cell ?

Comment: Try now. This function returns a range, not only the value. If you want only the value returned, then change first line to `as integer` and second last line to  `Set NextValue = num1.Offset(y, 0).value`

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  FYI I needed to remove the 'Set' command for next value at the end to get it to work when I set the answer to be 'as integer'.  If you can update that in your answer I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Indeed, the Set must be used only when working with a range. I have updatede it :)

Answer (score 1):

This will handle both *compact* ranges and *disjoint* ranges:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function SomethingElse(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim r As Range, values() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, strvalue As Variant
    ReDim values(1 To rng.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        values(i) = r.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    strvalue = values(rng.Count)

    For i = rng.Count To 1 Step -1
        If values(i) <> strvalue Then
            SomethingElse = values(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    SomethingElse = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me if you want an UDF or a code to be used in a macro

in the first case you've already been given answers

in the latter case you may want to consider these two options:

```
Public Function FirstDifferent(rng As Range) As Variant
    With rng.Parent.UsedRange
        With Intersect(.Resize(, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count), rng.EntireRow)
            .Value = rng.Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Array(1)
            FirstDifferent = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Value
            If FirstDifferent = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1) Then FirstDifferent = "#N/A"
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Function

Public Function FirstDifferent(rng As Range) As Variant
    With rng.Resize(, 1)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)
        FirstDifferent = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1).Value ' = 0 '<-- if any rows filtered other than headers one then change their column "B" value to zero
        If FirstDifferent = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1) Then FirstDifferent = "#N/A"
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Function
```